# Couldn't generate a APK folder (Gradle issue)

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, gradle

[image]

I can't seemed to generate the APK. and this pops up!

Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().

> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

Please assist.

Comment: Android studio is 3.6 and Ionic:

   Ionic CLI : 5.4.14

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v13.5.0
   npm    : 6.13.6
   OS     : Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Which is your global java version? 
Put some more information. **Ionic info** output and Android Studio version.

Try to downgrade your java version to 8

if you do not know how to change your java version, google it!